# Error in Doctrine Installation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, pear

I have followed the below steps to I install Doctrine on a linux terminal , please help me , where am i going wrong ?
..........

```
 1. sudo apt-get install php-pear////
 2. pear channel-discover pear.doctrine-project.org////
3.pear install doctrine/DoctrineORM-2.3.2(Unknown remote channel: pear.symfony.com
Unknown remote channel: pear.symfony.com
Unknown remote channel: pear.symfony.com
doctrine/DoctrineORM requires package "channel://pear.symfony.com/Console" (version >= 2.0.0)
doctrine/DoctrineORM requires package "channel://pear.symfony.com/Yaml" (version >= 2.0.0)
doctrine/DoctrineDBAL requires package "channel://pear.symfony.com/Console" (version >= 2.0.0)
downloading DoctrineCommon-2.3.0.tgz ...
Starting to download DoctrineCommon-2.3.0.tgz (59,473 bytes)
..............done: 59,473 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.doctrine-project.org/DoctrineCommon-2.3.0)////************
4./tmp# cd DoctrineORM-2.3.2(bash: cd: DoctrineORM-2.3.2: No such file or directory)////
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to discover the symfony channel, too:

```
$ pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
```

Comment: thank you , it has been installed , but what about this statement ...../tmp# cd DoctrineORM-2.3.2
bash: cd: DoctrineORM-2.3.2: No such file or directory

Comment: doctrine could not be installed because of missing dependencies, and thus got removed. A later part in the code tried to access the deleted file and failed.

Comment: can you please tell the solution for that

Comment: this is *not* a problem. Just discover the symfony channel, and run the install command again.

Comment: How to see the doctrine file
downloading DoctrineDBAL-2.3.2.tgz ...
Starting to download DoctrineDBAL-2.3.2.tgz (144,469 bytes)
...done: 144,469 bytes
downloading Console-2.2.0.tgz ...
Starting to download Console-2.2.0.tgz (63,673 bytes)
...done: 63,673 bytes
downloading Yaml-2.2.0.tgz ...
Starting to download Yaml-2.2.0.tgz (39,955 bytes)
...done: 39,955 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.symfony.com/Console-2.2.0
install ok: channel://pear.symfony.com/Yaml-2.2.0
install ok: channel://pear.doctrine-project.org/DoctrineDBAL-2.3.2
install ok: channel://pear.doctrine-project.org/DoctrineORM-2.3.2